# how to avoid sscanf() in C causing infinite while loop instead of storing user input?

Tags: c, string, multidimensional-array, while-loop, scanf

I've been working on a C project for a while now and I'm fairly new to C, I've tried multiple things by now but nothing seems to work. Whenever I enter my while loop and get to my sscanf() function, the loop becomes infinite and there is no ability to take the the input. Meaning that I cannot grab and store it in mt 2d array

I've also tried using strtok() as another option, but the code became too messy.

```
typedef struct item {
    char name[50];
    double price;
} item;


int main() {
    // 1 begins
    char userInput[100];
    printf("Hello, welcome to the shelf-O-matic!\n");

    printf("Please press enter and then type the number of shelves followed by ',' and number of slots\n");
    int shelf = 0;
    int slot = 0;
    scanf("%d , %d", &shelf, &slot);

    struct item **thing = malloc(shelf * sizeof(item));
    for (int i = 0; i < slot; i++) {
        thing[i] = malloc(slot * sizeof(item));
    }
    while (strcmp(userInput , "quit")!= 0) {

        //variables symbolizing the slots and shelves
        printf("type quit to exit or set input to the array\n");
        //scanf("%100s", userInput);

        //Putting the size in memory location


        double *cash = malloc(sizeof(cash));
        int *x = malloc(sizeof(x));
        int *y = malloc(sizeof(y));
        //scanf("%100s", userInput);

        // 1 ends
        char *itemName = malloc(sizeof(itemName));
        printf("Please add things to the shelves and slots by specifying <name> <price> <shelf> <slot> or type quit to finish adding\n");
        sscanf(userInput,"%100s, %lf, %d, %d", itemName, &cash, &x, &y);

     printf(itemName);
     printf(cash);
     printf(x);
     printf(y);


}

    return 0;
    }
```

The expected result should be the input taken into memory so it can be assigned to array values afterwards and printed out for validation.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here but your userInput should be initialized properly first, you can use something like this: char userInput[100]={'\0']; Also, you are assigning a new value to userInput by using sscanf inside while loop and this value is getting initialized based on itemName which only got malloc'ed but never been assigned any value. If you want to get a value for userInput from an user, then you should do a scanf using userInput.

Comment: I just tried it, sadly it hasn't changed the situation, the code I pasted is basically a test to see if the values are getting assigned to their variables, but the loop seems to become infinite the moment it hits the sscanf() line.

Comment: Infinite loop issue is caused by this statement: while(strcmp(userInput , "quit"). If this is not your full piece of code, you should debug your code by using a debugger.